# ASP.NET Core - Cannot serve static files - only default

Tags: asp.net-core

Basic ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app.

`Startup.cs` contains the following:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

In this scenario, when I try to browse to any HTML file in the webroot directory (i.e. project-dir / wwwroot), it does not get served. The webroot directory contains an `index.html` file and an 2nd HTML file. None can be served by typing the URL.

If I change `Startup.cs` to include default files like so:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

then the `index.html` file gets served. Even if I type the name of the other HTML file I get the `index.html` file (which is per the docs). So apparently the URL writer invoked by `UseDefaultFiles()` manages to handle this correctly but why is it not working by direct URL?

EDIT
I said above "when I try to browse to any HTML file in the webroot" but in fact I did not try "any" file but the ones I was working on which either had names like exports.html, index.html or files in a subfolder called "core". See my answer below for what I found.

Answer (score 4):

`UseStaticFiles()`, specifically serves the `wwwroot` project directory alone. You can customize which directory(ies) get served if you like.

When you say "webroot", I can only surmise you're talking about the project root, which will not be served by default. Calling `UseDefaultFiles()` changes this behavior somewhat to allow things like `index.html`, etc. to be served automatically, but does not cover static files in general.

The best thing you can do is just put everything in `wwwroot`. Anything there will be mapped to the document root automatically when using the static files middleware, so `wwwroot/index.html` will be available at `https://example.com/index.html`, and likewise, any static resources such as JS or CSS will be available as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the IIS server is not serving JS, CSS and Image files (static files). it happened to me in some deployment
Try this

**Windows 7**

1. Click Start, go to Control Panel and select Programs.
2. Under Programs and Features, choose Turn Windows features on or off. The Windows Features dialog box will appear.
3. Expand the root-level item Internet Information Services, expand World Wide Web Services, and then expand Common HTTP Features.
   Select the Static Content.

**Windows Server 2008**

1. Click Start, select All Programs
2. Choose Administrative Tools, and then select Server Manager.
3. In the navigation pane, select Roles, and then choose Add Roles.
4. In the Before You Begin window, click Next.
5. Go to Select Server Roles window > Web Server (IIS) > Next > Next.
6. In the Select Role Service window, expand Common HTTP Features
   then add Static Content

Comment: Thanks but IIS can serve static files allright. Curiously I can serve up JS files in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as simple as it is surprising:

Apparently, ASPNetCore does not accept certain strings as folder and file names.

Forbidden values are:

```
    exports
    core
```

And this means both for folder names and file names (i.e. exports.html won't work and a subfolder 'exports' makes trouble too.)

That's the two I found because those names occurred in my directory. There may be, and probably are, other names. I have found no documentation on this anywhere

But curiously, "index.html" is not working either. That works ONLY if I serve up that file by using app.UseDefaultFiles().

(Note to clarify - when I said in my original post "nothing gets served", in fact what was not getting served were files with the name "exports.html", and any files in a "core" subfolder. I did not test any and all files - when I made random test files with random names in the wwwroot folder, they did get served.)

There is still something amiss here but it works for what I need.